# Show my custom layouts in the "tools palette" when editing layouts

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Is it possible to show custom widgets and layouts that you've created in your projects as part of the tools palette in the layout editor?

There is a section called "Custom & Library Views" that is empty with a refresh button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Custom Layouts Requirements

For a custom layout to appear in the tools palette it must conform to the following:

1. You must implement a constructor that takes a `Context` and `Attributes` as parameters.
2. You must define custom attributes using the `<declare-styleable>` tags in the XML.

Here is an example of the constructor.

```
class PieChart extends View {
    public PieChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the attributes.

```
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="PieChart">
       <attr name="showText" format="boolean" />
       <attr name="labelPosition" format="enum">
           <enum name="left" value="0"/>
           <enum name="right" value="1"/>
       </attr>
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Further reading on [Creating Custom Views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html).